# Delete row in Custom Listview using SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I am creating a shopping cart in my app. I am using sqlite to store the values in a table to retrieve what the person added.

I have added a button for each row, so that when they click that button it will remove the row from the list and its data from the table.

But how do I call my delete function when the button is clicked? Thanks in advance!

this is my Adapter class:

```
public class ListCartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

private ArrayList<String> orderid;
private ArrayList<String> orderName;
private ArrayList<String> orderSize;
private ArrayList<String> orderQuantity;

public ListCartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> orderid, ArrayList<String> orderName, ArrayList<String> orderSize, ArrayList<String> orderQuantity){
  // public ListCartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> orderName){
    this.context = context;
    this.orderid = orderid;
    this.orderName = orderName;
    this.orderSize = orderSize;
    this.orderQuantity = orderQuantity;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return orderName.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return orderName.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item, null);

    TextView number = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textID);
    TextView name = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textOrderName);
    TextView size = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textOrderSize);
    TextView quantity = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textOrderQuantity);

    ImageButton btnRemove = (ImageButton) listView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);

    number.setText(orderid.get(position));
    name.setText(orderName.get(position));
    size.setText(orderSize.get(position));
    quantity.setText(orderQuantity.get(position));

    //BUTTON TO REMOVE ROW
    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           orderName.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    return listView;
}
```

and this is My SQLITEHELPER CLASS:

```
 public static final String DB_NAME = "CartDB";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Orders";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String NAME ="name";
public static final String SIZE ="size";
public static final String QUANTITY ="quantity";

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public cartDatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NAME + " VARCHAR, "
            + SIZE + " VARCHAR, "
            + QUANTITY + " VARCHAR);";

              db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST Orders";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addPerson(String name, String size, String quantity){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(SIZE,size);
    contentValues.put(QUANTITY,quantity);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


public Cursor getListContents(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}


public void removeSingleContact(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

   database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "= '" + id + "'");

    //Close the database
    database.close();
}
```

Comment: `" WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "= '" + id + "'");` id is an **INTEGER**. Don't treat it as if it was a **STRING**.

Comment: @Rotwang Okay Sir I will keep that in mind. How do you think I would tackle this problem sir?

Comment: Also, sql injection is bad. Learn about `database.delete` method

Comment: By simply removing the **string** markers (`'`) from the `id` variable.

Comment: @Rotwang No sir, I meant that how would I be able to call my delete function in the ListViewAdapter class so that when they click the button on that row. That row and its data would be deleted? :D

Comment: @cricket_007 yes sir I would look into that :D Thank you :)

Comment: By the way, SQL injection (are you using SQLite on a web server?!) can be avoided by using *parametric queries*.

Comment: @Rotwang ah sir, did you read my question? That is what is my problem

Comment: @Rotwang Because sir, I have made it work on ListView item click and it works, but I have added a button for each row so that when they click that button on that row. Then it would delete but I don't know how to tackle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved my question :D I still don't know why I was downvoted, but who cares.

This is the way to call your SqliteHelper in your Adapter class, add this code

```
final cartDatabaseHelper db = new cartDatabaseHelper(context);
```

I hope this helps other people with this problem :D